Water Damage between subfloor and hardwood floor
We are gutting out a bathroom and found the bedroom closet adjacent to it had always this rot smell. We found about 1 ft subfloor of wood next to the bathroom got weak and it looks like an old leak came towards the closet. Up on removing the thin hardwood floor we found this dark layer in between the wood floor and the subfloor but it is solid. Is this glue? If you hit the wood it is solid - only about one feet of subfloor that is next to the bathroom has this soft layer in it.
How should we address this? If we cut only about 1ft of adjacent subfloor, will it be ok? or should we remove the whole subfloor that has this dark layer in it?
The dark layer is stuck hard on the wood, it's not something that we could just wipe. But we are afraid that if we leave it there the rot smell might still linger?


The previous home owner made a small patch may be to fix the issue.


I would not be ripping up the entire floor to fix that unless it was necessary. I would continue to cut along the floor the way the previous owner did and examine the flooring and joists to see if more flooring needs to be removed, maybe to the next joist. The dark layer is probably some sort of adhesive from previous flooring and will be OK as long as the wood underneath is good.
